# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException while shutting down SpeechClient

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using Google Speech Client for converting speech to text, it is working fine but when I try to shut it down an exception is throwing.

This is the code I used for initialization.

```
private val mSpeechClient by lazy {

    applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credentials).use {
        SpeechClient.create(SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider { GoogleCredentials.fromStream(it) }
                .build())
    }
}
```

But when I call

```
mSpeechClient.shutDown()
```

it is throwing this exception.

```
 Process: com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition, PID: 10080
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@11065d8d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@3cbffe24[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:592)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.schedule(SerializingExecutor.java:93)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.execute(SerializingExecutor.java:86)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.closed(ClientCallImpl.java:594)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$DelayedStreamListener$4.run(DelayedStream.java:418)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$DelayedStreamListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedStream.java:372)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$DelayedStreamListener.closed(DelayedStream.java:415)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState.closeListener(AbstractClientStream.java:392)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState.access$300(AbstractClientStream.java:200)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState$1.run(AbstractClientStream.java:376)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState.deframerClosed(AbstractClientStream.java:245)
    at io.grpc.internal.Http2ClientStreamTransportState.deframerClosed(Http2ClientStreamTransportState.java:31)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientStream$TransportState.deframerClosed(OkHttpClientStream.java:275)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.close(MessageDeframer.java:233)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.closeWhenComplete(MessageDeframer.java:195)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream$TransportState.closeDeframer(AbstractStream.java:180)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState.transportReportStatus(AbstractClientStream.java:379)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport.startGoAway(OkHttpClientTransport.java:739)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport.access$1900(OkHttpClientTransport.java:92)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:936)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 3):

`RejectedExecutionException` is thrown because new tasks were apparently submitted to the `ThreadExecutor` after it has been shut down. This happens due to the default handler policy set in `ThreadExecutor` - `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy`.

> - In the default `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy`, the handler throws a
>     runtime `RejectedExecutionException` upon rejection.

Since you're **shutting down manually** your client `mSpeechClient.shutDown()` and inside of it the ThreadExecutor, to solve the problem you might want to change the handler policy to one of the following:

> - In `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the thread that invokes
>     execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback
>     control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are
>     submitted.
> - In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy`, a task that cannot
>     be executed is simply dropped.
> - In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy`, if the executor is not shut
>     down, the task at the head of the work queue is dropped, and then
>     execution is retried (which can fail again, causing this to be
>     repeated.)

Above, is the explanation of the descriptions of handler policies cited from [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) JavaDoc.

To do this, you'd need to create a custom instance of `ThreadExecutor` with a policy setting of your choice, and then pass it to your client. This should solve the problem.

Comment: But, it is working fine when I call it in onDestroy of activity, it only throws exception when I call it while my activity is open.

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukh I told you, the exception is thrown because you try to manually shut down the executor. I don't know why you want to do that, usually we leave the shutting down to the Android lifecycle.

Comment: I am using it as a voice search feature and when user is done with searching, I need to shut it down otherwise if I keep it open I get this exception com.google.api.gax.rpc.OutOfRangeException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: OUT_OF_RANGE: Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukh I can't help you with this particular case, as I have no experience with SpeechClient. All I told you is the reason for the exception to occur and possible ways of solving it. From there you're on your own unless..

Comment: Any Luck with this ??